# How to serve urls starting with particular path from one server and all others from another server using nginx?

Tags: linux, http, nginx, nginx-config

I have 3 Linux servers (CentOS) like below;

```
____________________________________________________
|  Name     |  Server  |  Network  |  IP           |
------------+----------+-----------+----------------
|  server0  |  nginx   |  public   |  public IP    |
|  server1  |  http    |  private  |  192.168.1.1  |
|  server2  |  http    |  private  |  192.168.1.2  |
------------+----------+-----------+----------------
```

Say I have a website `example.com` which hits `server0`. I have apache http server running in both `server1` and `server2`. I have all my html pages present inside `htdocs` directory in `server1`. When user request `https://example.com/page1.html` or `https://example.com/page2.html`, it should be delivered from `server1`. This is working fine.

I have some downloadable files like `file1.zip` and `file2.zip` in `server2`. Inside `htdocs` directory of `server2`, I have another sub-directory `downloads` and inside that, there are files `file1.zip` and `file2.zip`. I can access these files from my private network using the url `http://192.168.1.2/downloads/file1.zip` or `http://192.168.1.2/downloads/file2.zip`.

The requirement is, I want to access those files using url `https://example.com/downloads/file1.zip` and `https://example.com/downloads/file2.zip`. My existing nginx configuration (`nginx.conf`) is like below;

```
http {
    upstream server1 {
        server 192.168.1.1:80 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        server_name  example.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /download_files {
                rewrite ^/download_files(.*)$ http://192.168.1.2/$1 redirect;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass              http://server1;
        }

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
}
```

The above configuration is working fine for delivering html pages from `server1`, but I am getting timeout while trying to access download urls. Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying the config like below;

```
http {
    upstream server1 {
        server 192.168.1.1:80 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    upstream server2 {
        server 192.168.1.2:80 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        server_name  mydomain.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /download_files {
                rewrite ^/download_files(.*)$ http://192.168.1.2/$1 redirect;
        }

        location /download_files {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass              http://server2;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass              http://server1;
        }

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
}
```